# Transition to a specific view controller after a push notification. Different storyboard and different tab

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

When a push notification arrives, I want to send the user to a particular view controller (this view controller is the second one in the navigation hierarchy, and is also on the 3rd tab, and is also on a different storyboard). When the user is sent to this screen, I also want to maintain the navigation stack, so that the back button is visible, and when the back button is tapped, the user would need to be sent to the first one on that tab.

Here is my structure:

```
Storyboard1: tab1 -> VC1 
Storyboard2: tab2 -> VC2
Storyboard3: tab3 -> VC3a -> VC3b 
Storyboard4: tab4 -> VC4
```

When a push notification arrives, user should be sent to VC3b (which is defined in Storyboard3), and tapping the back button on that screen should take the user to VC3a. VC3b also has a variable called userId that I need set. I get the userId value through my notification.

What I have so far:

```
let userId = notification["userId"] as! String
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard3", bundle: nil)
let vc3b = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc3b") as! VC3b
vc3b.userId = userId
window?.rootViewController = vc3b
```

The above code doesn't work right. It just takes the user to the default screen of the app.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that 3rd tab is inserted inside a navigation controller  , so

```
let tab = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tab") as! UITabBarController {
tab.selectedIndex = 2 // third tab
self.window?.rootViewController = tab
let nav = tab.viewController![2] as! UINavigationController
nav.pushViewController(vc3b,animated:true)
```

Comment: Actually, the root is not the tab in my case. I have some login/onboarding screens before the user is taken to the tabs (I should have clarified). The tabs are defined in a separate storyboard called Tabs. How could I modify your code to accommodate this change?